# Windows application with react native

Tags: windows, react-native

I need to build a windows app of a form with react native which could connect to DNS for login. What things should I know? I know a little bit of JS
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed documentation (with inital setup) in the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2016/05/26/creating-universal-windows-apps-with-react-native/)

The app creation essentially requires knowledge of react-native-cli. Since you know a little bit of JS it will be better if you first dig into Node concepts to understand Advanced Javascript components (example: closures, callbacks), followed by React and then look into react-native-cli.